# Repeat character is not working in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I want to repeat a character in PowerShell. For example:

```
$test = "this is a test that I want to underline with --------"
Write-Host $test
Write-Host "-" * $test.length
```

However, the output with the above code is:

```
This is a test that I want to underline with --------
- * 53
```

Am I missing something really obvious?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Change:

```
Write-Host "-" * $test.length
```

to:

```
Write-Host $("-" * $test.length)
```

---

In argument mode, the parser interprets `"-" * $test.length` as three separate expandable strings - enclose them in a subexpression (`$()`) to have the entire expression evaluated before it's bound as a parameter argument.

You may want to [`Get-Help about_Parsing`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847892.aspx).

Comment: `write-host ("-" * $test.length)` should suffice.

Comment: @JosefZ Correct (`about_Parsing` describes this as well)